# Comma missing from ABNTeX2 citations

Tags: citing, abnt, abntex2

I am finishing writing a dissertation and the bibliographic references follow the ABNT standard. According to this standard, the indirect citation in the text must be of the type "[NAME, DATE]", as shown below

[image: FIGURA 1]

[image: FIGURA 2]

[image: FIGURA 3]

It happens that, to insert the comma automatically between the NAME and the DATE, I had to add `{,}` soon after the last surname of the reference in the `.bib` file, as shown in Figures 4. If you remove `{,}`, the comma disappears from the indirect quote. Can you fix this?

[image: FIGURA 4]

Comment: Please state the name of the bibliography style you employ. Please also state if you use a citation management package, say, `natbib`.

Comment: Whatever you do, you should not have to insert a literal comma into the `author` or `editor` field in order to get a comma between author and year in the citations. This should be resolved on the citation style side of things. In order to be able to help you we need to know which citation/bibliography packages you load (`cite`, `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) and which bibliography style. Ideally you would add a fully compilable, yet *short* example document that shows how you produce your citations to your question: http://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228, http://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407.

Comment: Anyhow: If you are using a package/style that claims to produce ABNT-compatible output, yet does not do so, that is definitely something you should also report to the developer/maintainer of said package. They can only fix problems if they get to know about them.

Comment: @Mico The packages I use related to references are: \usepackage[alf,bibjustif]{abntex2cite}, \usepackage{cite} and style comes from \bibliographystyle{abntex2}.

Comment: @moewe In my thesis, I use the bibitex and the packages mentioned above . The University provides a thesis model and I have been adapting it. It uses the inf-ufg style, which, according to her, easily integrates with the LATEX2e style.

Comment: @moewe I fully agree with you. I am in the final stages of completion here and I need to resolve it quickly. I want to, yes, report the problem to the future developer.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post a small, yet compilable example document (see the links in my first comment above)? I appreciate that you are pressed for time, but it would be much, much easier for us to help you, if you can show us an MWE that we can 'just run'. Otherwise we have to try and guess to recreate your document setup.

Answer (score 1):

Don't load the `cite` package when you are using `abntex2cite`.

Compare the output of the example below with the `cite` line commented out and uncommented.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}
\usepackage[alf,bibjustif]{abntex2cite}
%\usepackage{cite} % don't use this

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  Citing \cite{appleby}

  \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Citing (APPLEBY, 1980)]

Note that you don't need to set `\bibliographystyle` explicitly, `abntex2cite` can do that for you automatically.

If you really want square brackets around the citations, you may need

```
\citebrackets{[}{]}
```

Comment: It looks like you solved the problem, man. I will test each entry now. In few minutes,  I give the final answer.

Comment: @rsa, please select you kind friend's answer it it fit your needs. It's been weeks, not minutes, as of now.